# SQL How to assign letters to the query result group

Tags: sql

I have a query result as shown below (except the last column).
I want to add one more column ([assignletters]) to that result group by [pid].
This added column should be ascending letters (A,B,C...until J) with respect to ascending [id]

```
id  pid issuedate   rcvdate     (assignedletters)
1   1   2017-07-10  2020-07-11    A
2   1   2017-07-24  2017-07-25    B
3   48  2017-08-03  2017-08-03    A
4   48  2017-08-12  2017-08-13    B
5   104 2017-08-12  2017-08-13    A
6   104 2017-08-14  2017-08-15    B
7   104 2017-08-16  2017-08-16    C
```

Comment: Can you show us the query?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1):

In most databases, you can use `substr()` or `substring()` like this:

```
select t.*,
       substr('ABCDEFGHIJKLM',
              row_number() over (partition by pid order by id),
              1
             ) as assigned_letter
from t;
```

However, I would recommend just adding a number using `row_number()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `row_number` window function, like this (I'm putting here Presto syntax, but will work in most other DB, perhaps with slight differences):

```
WITH
   table1  (id, pid) AS
      ( SELECT * FROM ( VALUES (1,1),(2,1),(3,48),(4,48),(5,104),(6,104),(7,104) ) )

SELECT *, array['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'][row_number() over (partition by pid order by id)] assignedletters
FROM table1
ORDER BY id
```

Results:

```
id  pid assignedletters
1  1    a
2  1    b
3  48   a
4  48   b
5  104  a
6  104  b
7  104  c
```